# Adding product to cart - productAddToCartForm

Tags: javascript, frontend

We are running Magento Enterprise 1.12.0.2. This is on a staging and production server. On our production server when trying to add a product to the cart from the popup overlay we are getting the following Javascript error.

Uncaught ReferenceError: productAddToCartForm is not defined.

We are not getting the same error on our staging site.

Looking at cases where other people have had a similar issues we have checked the following.

Checked the code differences between the live and test sites and there are non.
We have also copied the code of the site from our live server to our test and this process works as expected.
Cleared all the cache on the server.

All the above are to no avail.

An example page of where this is broken is http://www.earlyyears.co.uk/physical-and-social-development/winther.
If you click on buy now to get the popup to add an item to basket then action of clicking "Add to Basket " returns the javascript error.

Any other pointers on where to look / how to resolve will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem it is with the New Relic Browser Monitoring injecting some Javascript that is breaking the iCart Javascript.